# fitsSystemWindows is not working with support libraries 27.1.1

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

I was using Android Support Library version 27.0.2. With that version I had this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="...Activity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarThemeBlack">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_..." />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

on v21 styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

on default theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>
```

With that configuration everything worked as expected. The toolbar color was the desired, the only way it shows up is adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true". Today I updated the Android Support Library to 27.1.1, and now the toolbar color is white, it looks like fitsSystemWindows stops working.

Here you can see what I mean.

[toolbar color changes before and after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAV1k.png)
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that replacing:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

by

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

solved the problem, where colorPrimaryDark is any color declared in the app.